# launching UIWebview with specific url

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I currently have a view with four buttons, and would like to be able to launch UIWebview with a specific url for each different button.

I currently am able to launch safari externally with the urls.

I know I can have the code to show the UIWebview within each button, and can set the url withing the viewDidLoad of the UIWebview, but I need a way to load a specific page depending on which button was pressed.

Regards

Answer (score 26, accepted):

somtheing like this should be called in the IBAction for  the buttom click. you can specify a different URL based on the sender

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)];  
webView.delegate = self;

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"www.url.com"] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: myTimeoutValue];  
[self.webView loadRequest: request];
```

Comment: So I dont need to add a webview in IB? I just implement the delegate in the code. What is the timeoutinterval in ? seconds integer?
Regards

Comment: add the webview in IB, timeout is in seconds

Comment: button* not buttom @AaronSaunders